# как перенести df в csv, чтобы избежать ошибки InputStream exceeded maximum size in bytes?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

Переношу результат запроса из `clickhouse` в `df`, чтобы потом перенести в `csv`, но падает с ошибкой `InputStream exceeded maximum size in bytes`

Какие есть варианты избежать ошибки?

```
query = '''

'''
data = pd.DataFrame()
date_start = pd.Timestamp('2023-02-01')
date_end = pd.Timestamp.today()
for i in range (0,250,1):
    date_low = date_start + pd.DateOffset(days = i)
    date_high = date_low + pd.DateOffset(days = 1)
    if date_low > date_end:
        break
    i_df = click_to_df(query.format(date_low, date_high),clickhouse ='_')
    data = data.append(i_df)
```

Comment: Полный стек трейс ошибки - прямо в вопрос. Сейчас даже непонятно, на какой строке падает. А вообще через append в цикле добавлять в датафрейм - это прежде всего очень долго. Лучше копить в список, а потом соединить через pd.concat, например.

Comment: он не падает на какой-то строчке, он падает из за большого размера df при переносе в csv

Comment: А перенос df в csv не кодом делается?

Comment: да, так и делаю

Comment: но падает с ошибкой InputStream exceeded maximum size in bytes из за большого df

Comment: Вот и покажите в вопросе именно тот код, на котором ошибка выходит. И полный стек-трейс этой ошибки.